# How can I customise Eclipse function comment block parsing?

Tags: eclipse, comments

If I have a block of code like this:

```
/**
 * function description text here
 * with
 * other
 * stuff
 * on 
 * multiple
 * lines
 */
function somefunction() ...
```

The function description on hovering the function will show the lines with a space in between, eg:

```
function description here

with

other

...
```

How can I customise the Eclipse function comment block parser to make it so that there is no extra space? Of course, I'd also like to customise it to do other things, but this seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Try and change from the following menu:

Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter>Edit >Comments Tab >General Settings